# Inkscape not launched on OpenShot

Tags: openshot

Inkscape not launched on OpenShot

OS - Ubuntu 22.04
OpenShot - v: 3.1.1

on OpenShot
Edit -> Preferences
Advanced Title Editor (path): /run/user/1000/doc/9264e32b/inkscape

On Terminal;
$ whereis inkscape

> inkscape: /usr/bin/inkscape /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/inkscape
> /usr/share/inkscape /usr/share/man/man1/inkscape.1.gz

Please help.  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Change the advanced title editor path to `/usr/bin/inkscape`